# How to access same instance of POJOs across multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a program which will process records from an Excel spreadsheet. Right now, it is taking a very long time to process over a large number of records (let's say 100,000).

This is what my class looks like so far:

```
public class RecordProcessor{
    private Map<Integer, String> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private List<Record> allRecordsToBeProcessed = new ArrayList<Record>();


    public static void main(String args[]){

         RecordProcessor processor = new RecordProcessor();

         processor.loadWorkbook();

         processor.processRecords();

         processor.writeOutput();

    }

    public void loadWorkbook(String excelPath){

         /**********************************
           1. Load the excel worksheet
           2. Populate all records into the allRecordsToBeProcessed object
         **********************************/

    }


    public void processRecords(){

          /**********************************
            Do the actual processing here.
          **********************************/
          int rowNumber= -1;

          for(Record record:allRecordsToBeProcessed){
               rowNumber++;
               String processingStatus = processRecord(record);
               this.statusMap.put(counter, processingStatus);
          }

    }

    private String processRecord(Record record){

           //Do something to process this record
          //Return either "SUCCESS" or a particular failure message

    }

    public void writeOutput(){
       //Write the output to the excel sheet

       for(int rowIndex:this.statusMap.keySet()){

           //Write this.statusMap.get(rowIndex) in row with Index rowIndex
       }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to split the processing to separate threads of 1,000 each, so that I can save time. So, in effect, I'll have 100 threads, each processing 1000 records.

Another requirement here, is that I've to update a cell against each row in my excel sheet indicating if the processing passed or failed for that particular record.

Here is what I can do:

1. I can write a method called `loadAndPaginate()` which will all the records into a number of `List<Record>` objects that contain 1,000 records each (as opposed to having one list containing all the 100,000 records)
2. I can create a class that implements the `Runnable` interface and have the `public String processRecord(Record record)` method in that implementation
3. I can then create the required number of Threads from this runnable implementation and call the `start()` method

I know this will process the 100,000 records and cut down the processing time a lot. But what I don't know how to do, is how to I update the status in my excel sheet?

I basically have to update `this.statusMap`  in my class (as shown above) from these threads that run concurrently.

I tried the following:

- Initialize `this.statusMap` from my calling class and pass it as a constructor value to my `Runnable` Implementation, but what I got in return was a map that was never updated.
- Other crude methods like each thread writing to a file with the statuses of all records they processed, and have my main thread read those files and write status to the excel after all threads stopped running (I was not satisfied with that approach)

Can someone guide me on the correct design?

**Editing my question in response to Jarrod's comments**

Sorry if my question felt too broad. I'm trying to make it crisp.

This is what I want to achieve

```
 public class RecordProcessor{

       private Map<Integer, String> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

       private List<List<Record>> paginatedRecords;

       //Let's assume I populate the above list like a List having 100 List<Record> that have 1000 Record objects each

       public void processRecords(){
            int i=-1;
            for(List<Record> records:this.paginatedRecords){
                 i++;

                 //The `RecordProcessorImpl` implements the `Runnable` interface and its `run()` method contains my logic to process a List of records
                 RecordProcessorImpl impl = new RecordProcessorImpl(records, this.statusMap);

                 Thread t = new Thread(impl, "ProcessorThread-" + i);
                 t.start();
            }
       }

 }
```

**At the end of it all**, I want `this.statusMap` to be updated with all the status I need to write for all my records in the Excel sheet.

The approach I've listed above doesn't work. My question is how to write to `this.stautsMap` from multiple threads?

I hope I'm precise this time.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: I just wanted to point out that using more threads than your CPU core count will effectively degrade performance for a mainly CPU-heavy task.

Comment: **off-topic: too broad** - *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: Hi there. Rather than writing the "Map-Reduce" functionality yourself, why don't you use a free multi-node grid tool like `hazelcast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the statusMap globally accessable you could make it a

```
public static Map<Integer, String> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Now it would be accessable with `RecordProcessor.statusMap`

The problem with this solution is, that it is not [thread safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). Fortunately Java provides a thread safe HashMap with [ConcurrentHashMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). So an implementation could look like

```
public static Map<Integer, String> statusMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Of course you can encapsulate the statusMap, if you want to.

```
RecordProcessorImpl impl = new RecordProcessorImpl(records);
```

In your RecordProcessorImpl you can now access the map with  `RecordProcessor.statusMap`, as stated above.